# JQuery UI dialog - How do I add buttons from an object

Tags: jquery-ui, object, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this code:

```
var bt = {}

bt = {
    text: "OK",
    click: function () {
        // Deletefunction here...
        $(this).remove()
    }
}, {
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function () {
        $(this).remove()
    }
}

$("#test").dialog({
    title: "Confirm deletion",
    width: "300px",
    buttons: [bt]
})
```

Why do I only see the OK button, and not the Cancel button?? JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/erBCS/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your assignment to `bt` does not do what you think it does. It ends up applying the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and is equivalent to:

```
bt = {
    text: "OK",
    click: function () {
        // Deletefunction here...
        $(this).remove();
    }
};
// Stray, ignored object literal.
{
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function () {
        $(this).remove();
    }
};
```

If you want `bt` to be an array, then make it so:

```
var bt = [{
    text: "OK",
    click: function () {
        // Deletefunction here...
        $(this).remove();
    }
}, {
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function () {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}];

$("#test").dialog({
    title: "Confirm deletion",
    width: "300px",
    buttons: bt
});
```